# JQuery disable a function when mobile view; and or when screen width is equal or less than 769px

Tags: jquery

I have hover state on my JQuery which is
this:

```
$('.navigation a').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).next('span').show();
        },
        function () {
            $(this).next('span').hide();
        }
    );
```

Now I want that hover state to disable whenever the user's screen resolution is 769px or lower.

Comment: So what is your particular question? You don't know how to get screen width? How to compare it with static value?

Comment: Do you mean you want the hover to disable and re-enable dynamically if the user changes the resolution while viewing your page (overkill, in my opinion), or just not bind the hover at all if the resolution is under your threshold at page load? Either way, try [`window.screen.width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.screen.width).

Comment: Just not bind the hover if the resolution is 769px and lower.

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer.

```
if ( $(window).width() > 769) {
$('.navigation a').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).next('span').show();
        },
        function () {
            $(this).next('span').hide();
        }
    );
}
```